# For loop through a nested-list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I noticed something very weird. I tried to look at where it was going wrong and realised that for some reason, the `nest[0]` list keeps changing midway through the loop.

```
>>> nest = [['prefix'],['line 1'],['line 2']]
>>> for part in nest[1:]:
...     list = nest[0]
...     list += part
...     print list
```

The output that I get is:

```
['prefix', 'line 1']
['prefix', 'line 1', 'line 2']
```

Whereas, what I need is:

```
['prefix', 'line 1']
['prefix', 'line 2']
```

Can somebody explain why this happens? I might be doing something very stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: with explanation of pointers, as requested

Your problem is that when you assign list to nest[0], you are not creating a new list, your just assigning a pointer. Your pointer is directed to the list containing ['prefix']

On your first iteration, you add something to this list

On your second iteration, you don't make a NEW list, you just repoint to the old one.

Then when you append again, you're appending to the old list!

What you mean is:

```
nest = [['prefix'],['line 1'],['line 2']]
for part in nest[1:]:
    list = [] + nest[0]
    list += part
    print list
```

There's several ways to think about this. Here's one. Say you had a deck of cards object:

```
myobj = Deck().
```

If I then say,

```
myobj2 = myobj,
```

I haven't created a new deck of cards, it would be like someone else looking at the deck I already have. We need to be able to do that to do a lot of programming (it's the fundamentals of object oriented design)! I would need to say

```
myobj3 = Deck()
```

to construct a new deck of cards object.

Consider:

```
myobj.shuffle #we're shuffling one deck, that two people are looking at
```

Both myobj and myobj2 will change.
Calling myobj3.shuffle leaves the other two untouched. What you've done told someone to re-look at the same deck, where you meant to make a new one!

Comment: Thank you. The code worked.

What I don't understand is why mine doesn't work. So when I try `list = ['prefix']`, I can see it does what I want it to. Why does pointing to the same object change it?

Comment: Post-EDIT : Thanks for the explanation. I am still trying to wrap my head around how that relates to my problem. Are you saying `nest[0]` is the `Deck()` object in your example?

Comment: Your "nest[0]" is the deck of cards. Calling list = nest[0] just tells us to look at the deck (which has the word 'prefix' in it) and then store that look-up in a place labeled "list". We never create a new deck of cards, or a new list, here. So when you append part to list, you're adding a new card to the deck. On next iteration, you call list = nest[0] again, but this just tells you to look back at the deck, which now has an extra card. When we add another card, we now have two extras. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

`list = nest[0]` mean you assign pointer to nest[0] to variable name `list`

If you want your expected output, you need to create a new list to make sure it will not effect the original.

```
nest = [['prefix'],['line 1'],['line 2']]
for part in nest[1:]:
    list = nest[0] + part
    print list
```

`nest[0] + part` will create a new value and assign to `list`

Answer (score 0):

this is just clarification in  simple words  :

the wrong

```
'list += part'
```

in

```
' for part in nest[1:]:
 list = nest[0]
 list += part
 print list'
```

the variable list will change its value in each iteration ..
I mean the varible list will assigned to the following values :

list = ['prefix']
then after the first iteration it will reassigned to be :

list = ['prefix' , 'line 1'] ## note the loop excute list +=part , if you continue it will get  all members of [nest]

so the solution focus on gitting seperate variable which keep its value constant in each iteration

```
'list = [] + nest[0]'
```